# Export image from Google Earth Engine and then open it in ArcGIS Pro. The pixel size is not correct

Tags: google-earth-engine, arcgis-pro

I exported an image from Google Earth Engine and then opened it in ArcGIS Pro. The cell size in the layer property was 8.98315284119486E-06. The original cell size should be one meter. The image looks normal in ArcGIS pro. Is this caused by unit difference? How can I fix it?

Comment: It is probably displayed in degrees instead of meters. If you didn't change the `crs` when exporting, Earth Engine uses the native projection of the dataset you are exporting. You can set `crs: "EPSG:3857"` in your call to export to get it projected in meters.

Comment: It succeeded! Thank you so much!

Comment: @JonasV you can submit your comment as an answer to the question, then 赵文轩
 can accept it.